# jQuery: Duplicate a table row and then alter the name of the inputs therein based on a specific naming convention?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a tricky situation where I need to duplicate a table row, and then alter the names of the inputs to a very specific format. The inputs are named as follows:

- *data[ProjectRequirement][0][description]*
- *data[ProjectRequirement][0][qty]*
- *...*

Now, when the above row is duplicated, the inputs need to be named as follows:

- *data[ProjectRequirement][1][description]*
- *data[ProjectRequirement][1][qty]*
- *...*

And so the pattern must continue. Duplicating the row is not a problem, and I have used the following method:

```
$j(\'table.WfTable tr\').live(\'mousedown\', function(e){
   if($j(e.target).hasClass(\'add\')){
      var clone = $j(e.target).parents(\'tr\').clone();
      $j(\'table.WfTable\').find(\'tbody\').append($j(clone));
      // NOW I WANT TO DO THE INPUT NAME CHANGE
   };
});
```

Ignore the escaped quotes, the JS is output via PHP. So at present, the row is duplicated and the names are the same. Is there a method whereby once duplicated, I can say:

*"get the name of each input in the row, look for a field like [0] or [1] etc and change that value to the value of the rows index number in the table DOM element (ie row 1 is index 0, 2 is index 1...)?"*

I can only assume that row 1 of table is at index 0 in the DOM tree of that table, and therefore think there must be a way to use that index data to apply to the input names?

Any help is much appreciated.

Simon

---

**EDIT: Here is one table row, created dynamically (cakePHP view)**

---

```
<tr class="repeat">
<td valign="top" style="width:250px;padding:10px 10px 10px 0;"><input type="hidden" name="data[ProjectRequirement][1][project_id]" value="1" id="ProjectRequirement1ProjectId"><input type="hidden" name="data[ProjectRequirement][1][id]" value="2" id="ProjectRequirement1Id"><div class="input text"><input name="data[ProjectRequirement][1][resource]" style="width:240px;" maxlength="40" type="text" value="Teachers" id="ProjectRequirement1Resource"></div></td>
<td valign="top" style="padding:10px 0;"><div class="input text"><input name="data[ProjectRequirement][1][description]" type="text" value="Any volunteer (part time) teachers" id="ProjectRequirement1Description"></div></td>
<td valign="top" style="width:150px;padding:10px 0;"><input name="data[ProjectRequirement][1][qty]" style="width:70px;float:left;clear:none;" maxlength="10" type="text" value="20+" id="ProjectRequirement1Qty"> <a href="#" class="add"><img src="/trusthau.net/img/buttons/btn_plus.png" style="float:right;clear:none;margin:10px 0 0 0;" class="add" alt=""></a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What does one table row look like?

Comment: @ yunze, please see edit below my question, I have added a row that has been output (via CakePHP)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('#table tr.repeat:last').clone().appendTo('#table');
    $('#table tr.repeat:last td input').each(function(){
        var input = $(this),
            name = input.attr('name');
        name = name.replace(/(\d+)/, function(i) {
            return ++i;
        });
        input.attr('name', name);
    })
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZFNDD/4/

Comment: Victor, this looks very promising, I am going to give this a shot now. Thank you.

Comment: You absolute life saver, this worked a treat, thank you 10x over!

Comment: I did however have to change one thing. Because there is an add button on each row, if I add a 3rd row and it becomes 3, and then click the add button on row 1, the last row is row 2, which is incorrect. I changed the return function to be as follows:

`return $j(\'table.WfTable tr.repeat\').size()-1;`

So that it would get the number of rows in the table -1 (so index is correct)

Comment: For some reason *replace* didn't work because *name* wasn't a string, instantiated a new string with name's content before the *replace* call fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use last(jQuery('selector').last()) function in the jQuery code which would give you the last row every time.This would give you the appended row and then you can alter the input values by first collecting the number of rows present in the table.

I'm considering that there is going to be duplication of each and every row

Comment: This will not really work, because I may not always know how many inputs will be in each row. The issue not duplicating them, the issue is finding a way to traverse the input elements in the duplicated row and change them accordingly.